# Is Invoking window.alert a synchronous operation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, cross-browser

On executing openAlert function in chrome console, log doesn't appear in console until I close the alert window.

```
function openAlert(){
    window.alert("Alert open");
    console.log("alert done");
}
```

Is invoking window.alert a synchronous operation?
If it is, then why? As it will block all background work (network calls, time intervals, etc).

Comment: Have a look at [Is JavaScript guaranteed to be single-threaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2734025/1048572)

Comment: `alert`, `confirm` and ´prompt` are deprecated just because of this. Don't use them any more.

Comment: Thanks, It was a nice read. Closing my question.